# Get field names from Stored Procedure with Dapper

Tags: .net, dapper

I am executing a stored procedure with Dapper like this:

```
var sprocResult = conn.Query("TestSproc", new {clientID = 2}, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
```

I can enumerate the results and list the values.  What I need to be able to do though is also enumerate the field names that come back from the sproc.  I will not know these field names at design time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When using the `dynamic` API (the `Query(...)` instead of `Query<T>(...)`, as per your example), each row also implements `IDictionary<string,object>`. So basically:

```
foreach(IDictionary<string,object> row in sprocResult)
{
    var colNames = row.Keys;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the query may return no rows, the `Query().First().Keys` does not work. In this case, you can use `ExecuteReader().GetName(i)`.